# Head 404 dependency issue when trying to write to Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have storage and inside Blob with public access. 
but when I am trying to write a document live telemetry shows below Dependency error.

1:21:57 PM | Dependency | 404 | 65 
HEAD imagesa| LogLevel=Information | Blob=255274.jpg

Time:   1:21:57 PM

Duration:   65 ms

Outgoing Command:   HEAD imagesa

Result code:    404

```
fileName =imageURL.Substring(imageURL.LastIndexOf(@"/") + 1);
var req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(imageURL);
            using (Stream filestream = req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
            {
                // Get the reference to the block blob from the container
                CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
            //create a snapshot
            bool existsTask = await blockBlob.ExistsAsync();
            if (existsTask == true)
            {
                //  the base blob's metadata is copied to the snapshot.
                await blockBlob.CreateSnapshotAsync();
                blockBlob.Metadata.Clear();
            }
}
```

Comment: Without seeing any code, exceptions, or additional context, I don't think this can be answered, as written. Do *any* writes work? If so, what's different about this specific write? Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Hello, have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your issue with the same code in a console app(And if you run your code with some special setting/environment, please point it out).

Please make sure somethings:

1.check if you have set the blob access to public in azure portal, and check your code if use the same blob / container.

2.please use the latest version of `WindowsAzure.Storage` package, 9.3.3.

And one thing you also need to know: after the code `blockBlob.Metadata.Clear()`, you need use `blockBlob.SetMetadata()`. Or it will not clear the metadata.

The code I used:

```
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials("account", "key"), true);
            CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            var cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("test-2");

            var imageURL = "https://xx.blob.core.windows.net/test-2/sample.JPG";

            var fileName = imageURL.Substring(imageURL.LastIndexOf(@"/") + 1);
            var req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(imageURL);
            using (Stream filestream = req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
            {
                CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);

                bool existsTask = await blockBlob.ExistsAsync();

                if (existsTask == true)
                {                    
                    await blockBlob.CreateSnapshotAsync();                   
                    blockBlob.Metadata.Clear();
                    blockBlob.SetMetadata(); // add this line of code to ensure the changes to metadata is committed.
                }
            }
```

Please let me know if you have more issues.